# Set margin to "standalone" view

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

This might be just bad practice, but android gui keeps frustrating me as always. I have this standalone view called primary_button under res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
    android:textColor="@color/light_warm_gray"/>
```

and its custom background "primary_button" shape under res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@color/light_olive" />
   <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
   <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Now the problem is, when I set layout_margin to say 10dp, nothing is set because at that point when I inflate using that line:

```
Button b = (Button)View.inflate(this, R.layout.primary_button, null);
```

it has no layout parent (obviously needs to set layout params). I want neat code, and setting *Layout.LayoutParams in code all the time is a pain.

Shape padding, and button padding, didn't do what I wanted, but what they are intended to do. (In that case they just enlarged the button shape)

Another way i thought of, was to set a zero-alpha stroke around it, but that is a horrible solution.

I wonder how the stock buttons handle this. I mean they just leave a nice margin between them (around 15dp?) without having to set layout params. Shouldn't this somehow happen with a custom view as well?

Comment: Add the code that you use to inflate the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
View.inflate(this, R.layout.primary_button, parentView);
```

I suppose there is an add view method called later. try both by keeping it and removing it.

Comment: no my friend, I just checked it. The parent view is a linearLayout in that case called ll and so I used it like this: `Button b = (Button)View.inflate(this, R.layout.primary_button, ll);` . It gives me an invalid cast exception (tries to cast linearLayout to button) internally at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: no, again. Using just this simple statement `View.inflate(this, R.layout.primary_button, parentView);` the cast exception still happens (because it gets thrown in android, not in my code). So it's not the casting of the returned view to button, but linear layout ll cast to button from the LayoutInlfater class.

Comment: it worked my friend, i had another forgotten button at the bottom. sorry to bother you more!